# CSS Transition Not animating both ways

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a header than I animate in by adding a class. My issue is that it animates going down, but not back up. Scrolling back up it disappears with no transition.

The HTML:

```
<header id="masthead-fixed" class="site-header">
header content here
</header>
```

The JS is triggered on scroll when scrolled past a certain distance.

When past a certain point:

```
jQuery('#masthead-fixed').addClass("stick");
```

When above that point:

```
jQuery('#masthead-fixed').removeClass("stick");
```

The Sass:

```
header#masthead-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: -73px;
    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease, top 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease, top 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease, top 1s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease, top 1s ease;
    transition: opacity 1s ease, top 1s ease;


    &.stick {
        opacity: 1;
        top: 0;
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Try creating a [mcve] so we can see the issue directly on the question. I tested your code and the animation works fine both going down and back up. Could it be that there is other CSS that is affecting the styling of the header?

Comment: You write top: 0; but with translateY (-heightELem) also animate already it